# Is it possible to hide/delete maximize button in wxWidgets C++?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, maximize

I'm writing app in wxWidgets C++ version (using linux but I want to cross-compile to win) for my friend who plays RPG games.Quite simple app - 8 buttons imitating dices with diffrent sizes, and one static text showing the result of the randomizing. 
I've made the Window "static" - it is impossible to maximize it or ... generally change the size of the main window. So, I want to make the icon "maximize" hidden or deleted. I've been searching. However, I haven't found the solution. I've only disabled the button using

```
MainFrame::MainFrame(const wxString &title): wxFrame (
NULL, wxID_ANY, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(290,180),
wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~(wxRESIZE_BORDER | wxMAXIMIZE_BOX))
```

So, it it possible to make the icon "hidden" or "deleted" ?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you can either have none of the buttons (including the close button) like this:-

```
style = wxCAPTION;
MainFrame::MainFrame(const wxString &title): wxFrame (NULL, wxID_ANY, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(290,180), style)
```

or you get all 3 buttons but with some disabled:-

```
style = wxCAPTION | wxSYSTEM_MENU | wxMINIMIZE_BOX;
MainFrame::MainFrame(const wxString &title): wxFrame (NULL, wxID_ANY, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(290,180), style)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Finally, I used GridSizer so the topic could be closed.

Comment: How did GridSizer solve the problem with the display of the Maximize button? Does it now make the button relevant by doing intelligent resizing with a larger screen area?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I don't have to care about maximizing ;)