# How to disable maximize button in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I need to disable maximize for my wxWidgets program. What code should I add to my frame in order to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to hide/delete maximize button in wxWidgets C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179460/is-it-possible-to-hide-delete-maximize-button-in-wxwidgets-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derived your class like following :

```
TestFrame::TestFrame(wxWindow* parent)
  : wxFrame(parent, wxID_ANY, main_frame_title_str, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxSYSTEM_MENU | wxRESIZE_BORDER | wxMINIMIZE_BOX | wxCLOSE_BOX | wxCAPTION | wxCLIP_CHILDREN)
```

Then you disable maximize.

Comment: It is better to use `wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~wxMAXIMIZE_BOX` as it is more correct and more clear.

Comment: or you can also use `wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wxMAXIMIZE_BOX`

Comment: This unfortunately does not work for me. The windows still opens on mac OS with the enabled maximize button :/

Comment: Not perfect on Windows: it can still be minimized by double-clicking on the title bar.